# MQL4 StringToDouble alters the value of the variable?

Tags: mql4

MQL4 documentation states that the value limits for double type variables is:

```
"Minimal Positive Value" = 2.2250738585072014e-308
"Maximum Value"          = 1.7976931348623158e+308
```

See https://docs.mql4.com/basis/types/double

Why does `StringToDouble()` alter the value converted?

Am I doing one thing while expecting a different result?

```
void OnStart() {
  string s1 = "5554535251504900090807060504030201";
  double d1 = StringToDouble(s1);
  string s2 = DoubleToString(d1);

  Print("s2<",s2,">");
  printf("%099.8f",d1);
  Print("s1<",s1,">");
     
  return;<br>
}
```

Here's what I get when I run that code:

```
s1<5554535251504900090807060504030201>
d1<000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005554535251504899684469244159852544.00000000>
s2<5554535251504899684469244159852544>
```

`5554535251504900090807060504030201` amounts to
`5.55454E+33`.

Obviously, that doesn't even come remotely close to the `1.7976931348623158e+308` limit.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"What am I missing here?"*

The documented facts.

MQL4 uses no more than **`4`**-bytes to store **`int`**.
MQL4 uses no more than **`8`**-bytes to store **`double`**.

IEEE-754 standard defines the rest - how many bits from those 64 are reserved for:
 exponent `( -308, 0, +308 )`
sign `( +, - )` and 
the rest, for normalised form of the ***mantissa*** : `0.???????...????`

Argument, that an actual number is far from either "edge" of **`< DBL_MIN, DBL_MAX >`** does explain nothing about the shallow-ness of the exact number *reduced*-precision representation ( see `DBL_EPSILON ~ 2E-16` or `DBL_DIG ~ 15`-significant digits, or `DBL_MANT_DIG ~ 53`-bits, left from a 64-bit ( 8-Byte ) storage-cell for mantissa ).

There are many numbers, that simply cannot be stored exactly, using IEEE-754 floating point number representation.

Tons of literature explain this, so feel free to dig deeper, or may use another tools, that rely on infinite-*(unlimited)*-precision number representation, should your use-case requires that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This was driving me up a wall.

OK, the standard from [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Representation_and_encoding_in_memory) says double has 15.95 decimal digits, which I take to mean a total of 1595 significant places(!?) So I've actually got more to work with than I thought.

Comment: I'm actually in the process of working around another silly limitation of this 80s-90s vintage language. It lets you set global variables, _but only if they're double data types_ lol. So, I'm taking a string, using the character code for each character, shifting the value down by 48 so that they're all no more than 2 digits (which gives me all I need), then building a "number" made up of those digits all strung together. Pack, store, retrieve, and unpack, voila! Global string variables of up to 797 characters. :)

Comment: So now all I need to do as add a little code to place a decimal in the char code string at the 16th position and I'll be good to go.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and the clear explanation!

Comment: Glad @skeptic23 you've found the answer helpful. Feel free to click **[ Accept ]** to mark the Answer accepted. That is the way StackOverflow Community confirms the best Answer provided :o)

Comment: LMAO! What a dummy. (me I mean) No, not 1595 places, values. 110 places. Still cool. Enough to meet my needs.